# Java: How do i get the int that i need??? by using something to split them?

Tags: java, string, split, int, shapes

```
int x1;
int y1;
int x2;
int y2;

String shape = " sequenceNumber <Square> 50 60 70 90 </Square> "

public splitThem(String s){

 //I can't  figure out how to extract the information i need...
 //... Do sometthing to extract splitThem(shape)
  int this.x1 = parseString("50"); 
  int this.y1 = parseString("60"); 
  int this.x2 = parseString("70"); 
  int this.y2 = parseString("90"); 

}

public void Graphics(graphic g){
    g.drawRect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

I'm wondering if theres a way to extract the information that i need and parseString them to integer??? something like split method??

Comment: The String that is shape - where does it come from - is it really like that, is it part of an XML do you have something that formally defines what it is?

Comment: I have to input them manually

Comment: But im not there yet.. What i have to do is i input something like the format <shape> x y x y </shape>

Comment: Then i need some function to extract what i input and put them into the variable and draw the shape

Comment: so something like XML but not XML?

Comment: I think its like the format xml

Comment: @user3281912 check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split string to array string using [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
Then, parse some elements of this array.

```
public void splitThem(String s){
        // Split string to array
        String[] array = s.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        // Parse 
        this.x1 = Integer.parseInt(array[3]); 
        this.y1 = Integer.parseInt(array[4]); 
        this.x2 = Integer.parseInt(array[5]); 
        this.y2 = Integer.parseInt(array[6]); 
        System.out.println(x1);
        System.out.println(y1);
        System.out.println(x2);
        System.out.println(y2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scan that String with a `Scanner`, and by using `nextInt()` you can grasp the integer values.

```
String s = " sequenceNumber <Square> 50 60 70 90 </Square> ";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

After execution of the code above, you can set your shape coordinates with the values from integer list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.parseInt but also don't have int before this.x1

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Also use shape.split in a space you will get close.

You can start with shape.substring and shape.indexOf to get just the string with numbers.

I don't want to give you the code but you may find this helpful.

http://codingbat.com/doc/java-string-indexof-parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

It kind of looks like you're wanting to parse XML and then parse the content of a text node.

```
String shape = "<Square> 50 60 70 90 </Square>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(shape)));
Element square = document.getDocumentElement();
String textContent = square.getTextContent().trim();
String[] numbers = textContent.split(" ");
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int y1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
int x2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);
int y2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[3]);
```

Comment: Computers are stupid, you need to work out for yourself a way to explain to them exactly what you need them to do if you don't they can't do it. Right now you don't seem to know what you want the computer to do - I'd suggest going back to your teacher and ask them to clarify the requirements - this is how all programming works all the time you constantly need to clarify exactly what people are wanting / meaning.